# For this recursive code why does Python 2.7 not give a stack overflow error but 3.5 does?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

Earlier today I read about this strange case in `Python`, `Java` & `JS`:

```
try:
    return True
finally:
    return False
```

Which returns `False`.

So, I decided to toy around with it:

```py
def caseThree():
    try:
        caseThree()
    except:
        print("Error")
        caseThree()
    finally:
        return False
print(caseThree())
```

In Python `2.7` this returns:

```
Error
False
```

However, in Python `3.5`:

```
Error
Fatal Python error: Cannot recover from stack overflow.

Current thread 0x000025ec (most recent call first):
  File "`<stdin>`", line 3 in caseThree
```

the last line is repeated until you eventually get: `...`

Can anyone explain why `2.7`'s code doesn't result in a stack overflow, while `3.5` does?

Comment: *"the only difference is that we moved the recursion from the finally to the try"* - why did you expect that this *wouldn't* change the output? It's not clear what is surprising you here, or why. Could you focus on one specific problem?

Comment: 1. `RecursionError` (`RuntimeError` before Python 3.5) is just an exception and may be caught and handled by `try/except/finally` constructs. 2. `finally` block have to be executed. These two statements is all you need to interpret what's happening in your code.

Comment: Edited the question to focus on one problem, as suggested by @jonrsharpe

Comment: Could you fix the title? We're not aspiring to click bait here!

Comment: Not exactly sure why 2 people have voted to close as "unclear what you're asking". It's pretty clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the error *you're* encountering is actually expected, as it is explicitly tested for in `Lib/test/test_sys.py` function [`test_recursionlimit_fatalerror`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/c30098c8c6014f3340a369a31df9c74bdbacc269/Lib/test/test_sys.py#L259).

Now, without criticizing your colorful experiments, this is *also* the cause of a bug that causes a segfault (sometimes, see issue); there has already been one report of this to [the Python bug tracker](https://bugs.python.org/) as [issue 28179](https://bugs.python.org/issue28179).

Keep an eye on that thread if you're curious as to what is causing this.